# outerHTML and attribute updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, outerhtml

I'm trying to get the HTML code as a string with the attribute updates.

I've a `select` tag, whose options I update using JavaScript.

By default, a first `option` is `selected` using the HTML attribute `selected="selected"`.

If I unset `selected` from the first option using `option1.selected = false` and set `option2.selected = true` for the second `option`, and then call the `outerHTML` of a `select`, I get

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
```

As you can see, `selected` attribute is still on the first `option`, while it has been moved to the second `option`. The expected result is

```
<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option selected="selected">two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
```

Here's an example http://jsbin.com/adAbAMe/2/edit?html,js,console,output (click `run with js` to get a result) which shows, that if a `selected` attribute has been changed, it doesn't change in the HTML code.

But I need to get the final HTML from outerHTML with the successful attribute updates, because if I move this `select` somewhere I won't get any updates I've made before using JavaScript.

Is there any method to get the HTML as a string with the real attributes values?

Comment: The attribute `selected` is only used to set the initial value, after that what ever changes is made will get reflected in the attribute

Comment: one solution will be is to write a change handler which will update the attribute

Comment: Um that jsbin is actually working for me lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selected` attribute isn't automatically updated, but you can set it to be removed and added to the proper elements.

```
//remove "selected" from first
if (i==0) {
  option.selected = false;
  option.removeAttribute("selected");
}

//add "selected" to second
if (i==1) {
  option.selected = true;
  option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsbin.com/adAbAMe/4).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
```

and

```
option.removeAttribute('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('button').click(function () {
    console.log($('select').prop('outerHTML'))
})

$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).find('option[selected]').removeAttr('selected');
    $(this).find('option:selected').attr('selected', 'selected');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XrV8s/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [DOM Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70874476):

> **selected** of type **boolean**
>
> Represents the current state of the corresponding form control, in an interactive user agent. Changing this attribute changes the state of the form control, *but does not change the value of the HTML selected attribute of the element.*

*(emphasis mine)*

To get the effect you're looking for, you want `option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected')`, though you'll also need `option.removeAtrribute('selected')` on the other options.